# How to copy a dom element in vue3

Tags: firebase, vue.js, v-for

here is what I want to do:

When the user clicks on a photo, I whant to copy the photo and make it appear in the side bar. I don't whant to move the original image, I whant a copy of it to appear.

the thing is that these images ar imported in a v-for loop. So I don't have a variable containg the image.

```
<li v-for="doc in documents" :key="doc.id">
    <div class="find">   
        <img :src="doc.url">
    </div>    
                                
</li>
```

I have documents containing all the images imported from firebase firestore.

How could I do this without downloading the image again?

thanks in advance!!

eric

Comment: If the image has already loaded and the resource has the appropriate cache headers, the browser will just serve the cached image instead of downloading it again.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help... cache headers? what are those?

Comment: They're [headers](https://www.imperva.com/learn/performance/cache-control/) set by the server.